# c# Add new name in MS Excel name manager using value not coordinates

Tags: c#, excel

I want to add a name and a value in name manager not coordinates as follows:

```
name     | value                      | refers to
---------+----------------------------+-------------
fruits   | {"banana";"apple"}         |
movie    | {"kingkong";"HarryPorter"} |
```

This code is add 'name' and 'refers to' column

```
public void addName(Excel.Worksheet sheet)
{
    Excel.Names names = sheet.Names;
    string[] text = { "test1", "test2" };
    Excel.Name name = names.Add("Test", text);
}
```

How can I handle the value of the name manager?

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the array of strings into a single correctly formatted string to pass as the refersTo argument. Join with a ',' to get the value lined up in a row, join with a ';' to get them lined up in a column.

```
public void addName(Excel.Worksheet sheet)
{
    Excel.Names names = sheet.Names;
    string[] names = {"test1", "test2"};
    string refersToString = "={\"" + String.Join("\",\"", names) + "\"}";
    Excel.name = names.add("Test", refersToString);
}
```

This is equivalent to:

```
public void addName(Excel.Worksheet sheet)
{
    Excel.Names names = sheet.Names;
    Excel.name = names.add("Test", "={\"test1\",\"test2\"}");
}
```

Comment: Is it possible without adding a value to cell??

Comment: Yes, the values are stored in the named range, not cells, if you manually punch them in as shown.